# Induction proof over the product of two sums

Tags: real-analysis, induction

so part of my homework is the following problem:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ x_1,x_2,..,x_n \gt 0$. Show that:
$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n{x_k} \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{x_k}} \right) \geq n^2$$

I thought proof by induction is a good choice here and well the case $n=1$ seems straight forward here. But in my induction step I am currently trying to show that:
$$\left( \frac{1}{x_{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n{x_k} \right)+\left( x_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{x_k}} \right)\geq 2n$$

which seems right - equality if all $x_k$ are equal I believe. So i guess that if we form that to:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{x_k}{x_{n+1}}+\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_k}}$$
We should be able to estimate the sum the way we need it here.

Can anyone help? As this is homework I would be happy if you guys wait a bit with full solutions and just post hints for the moment I open up the question. Thank you! (Also someone might edit the title - couldnt think of a better one)

Comment: Are the $x_i$ distinct?

Comment: @User203940 I believe that some of the $x_k$ could be equal as well.

Comment: Try combining the fractions you have in the final sum and reasoning about $x^2+y^2 -2xy$.

Comment: @platty thank you! I thought estimating would be harder with the squares if $x_k$ was between 0 and 1. It's totally clear now.